# Merge lines symbology with transparency using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I've made a categorized symbology type of lines stroke width is from a column values :
[image]

And I put some transparency.

For features with the same color, can the color be merged between the features with they touch or cross?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `layer group`, add the layer(s) of interest to it, then style the group and set the opacity / transparency there. It would be applied on all features of the layer(s) at once:

[image]

As a consequence, the transparency between the lines of the same layer won't be shown either. You might have to create several groups, one per line category, to create the same effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the second point : instead of creating several groups you can use the "Symbol levels" and define the order of the layers
[image]